# What does test bl al, bl al mean?

Tags: assembly, x86

In a website I`ve seen a command like this:

```
test bl al, bl al

jz 0xaddress
```

What does this mean?

Does this belong to a specific compiler to generate such these assembly codes?

Comment: where is this output from? looks like a buggy disassembler.

Comment: This is not a valid x86 assembly instruction, could you perhaps attach a print screen or a direct copy of the instruction in front of you?

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking about x86 assembly, then the syntax is invalid as the TEST instruction works on two operands

the correct syntax would TEST op1,op2 and it'll perform a bitwise AND on op1 and op2, discard the result, and change the flags accordingly

> Source
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST_(x86_instruction)

Comment: inevitably your are right. I have confused when I`ve seen this command.

Comment: glad I could help. make sure to specify what type of assembly we're talking about in the tags/question next time.

Comment: I forgot to mention x86. But no good answer yet. I think it has another answer...